# addClass in jQuery is not adding a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been searching for an answer for this question but still, my problem exists. I tried all the answers from here (StackOverflow) and from other websites but it still didn't solved my problem.

Additional Information:
There's no error on DevTools.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="nav">
   <div class="container">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="sample.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
/*Nav Styles*/
.nav li {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
}

.nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

/*Active Menu*/
.activeMenu {
 color: red;
}
```

JS:

```js
var x = function(){
 $('.nav li').click(function(){
        //alert($(this).text()); <-- It's working
  $(this).addClass('activeMenu');
  return false;
 });
};

$(document).ready(x);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try this `$(document).ready(x(););`

Comment: `x()` instead of just `x` would work.

Comment: OPs ready handler code is fine - he is providing the `x` function as the handler instead of a more common anonymous function syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because your CSS rule for `.activeMenu` is not specific enough to override the colour set on the `a` element. You need to make the rule more specific:

```
.activeMenu a {
    color: red;
}
```

Or set `!important` on it. The former is better practice.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wvg9gywn/)

Comment: Wow great. Thanks! I should practice more in css since i'm still learning web development. I'd accept it after 7 minutes ('coz it says You can accept an answer in 7 minutes). Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You must change your css too:

.activeMenu a {
       color: red;
   }

```js
var x = function(){
 $('.nav li').click(function(){
        //alert($(this).text()); <-- It's working
  $(this).addClass('activeMenu');
  return false;
 });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  x();
});
```

```css
.nav li {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
}

.nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

/*Active Menu*/
.activeMenu a {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
   <div class="container">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is logically no different, you've just padded it out with another anonymous function.